# I don't know how to code my query sentence on Core Data with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I am a new hand to Core Data,I don't know how to write some query sentence for NSPredicate and meet some problem.Please help to find my problem and give me some suggestion to achieve my query aim.For example,now I Have a table ,it has some data .(As the picture show)[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFvc.png)

The data in the table with the month attribute "2015/03/01 00:00:00".Now,I want to query a date which month is began with 2015/03,I code "fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month BEGINSWITH[cd] %@/0%@", year,month)" or "fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month LIKE[c] %@/0%@", year,month)",am I right?(year=2015,month=03)
If not,I really hope someone can help me.And another question is the 'cd/c' in [] means what?Is it set structures?The code as follow:

```
    func remove(model:MonthlySummery) -> Int {
    let cxt = self.managedObjectContext!
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MonthlySummery", inManagedObjectContext: cxt)
    let component = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year,.Month], fromDate: model.month!)
    let year = component.year
    let month = component.month
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    NSLog("month == %i/0%i", year,month)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month BEGINSWITH[cd] %@/0%@", year,month)
    do{
        let listData = try cxt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as NSArray!
        if listData.count > 0 {
            let dailyRecord = listData.lastObject as! NSManagedObject
            cxt.deleteObject(dailyRecord)
            if cxt.hasChanges {
                try cxt.save()
            }
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("Remove failure!")
        let nserror = error as NSError
        NSLog("Error: \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to parse dates by relying on formatted date strings.

Refactor your code to use proper dates. The `NSManagedObject` subclass should have a property of type `NSDate`. In the actual SQLite database, this will be represented by a long number, but you should not be interested in that.

You then calculate start and end date of particular month and use a predicate like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "month >= %@ && month < %@", start, end)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mundi,I get it,now,I have another idea to solve this problem,I am going to reconstitute my datebase,changing the month attribute from NSDate to String,because I can  set any format I wanted through NSDataFormatter.For example,if i want month string,I can set dateFormat = "yyyy-mm",if I want day string,I can set dataFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd".Do you think so?

Comment: As I said, this is a potentially disastrous idea. You should be using NSDate which is used to represent dates. Strings are not very good doing this job.

Comment: Listen to me,if i use NSDate to represent dates,I will don't know how to code predicate sentence.NSDate default format is "2015/04/12 00:00:00".Now,if I want to query a data on some day,I don't need "00:00:00" in "2015/04/12 00:00:00".If i need to query a data on month,I don't need "/12 00:00:00" in "2015/04/12 00:00:00",just need "2015/04",do you understand?Or can you teach me to code the query sentence?I will be very thankful to you

Comment: As stated, relying on string representation of dates is an erroneous strategy. The date contains the month and day as well, so there is all the information you need. I have shown you how to write the predicate.

Comment: Thank you again Mundi,nice to meet you!I am benefit a lots from you!